# How do I intuitively understand what this linear transformation matrix is?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

I know how to get the product when given another matrix. But how do I know what this matrix is doing simply by looking at it?

Comment: Applied to $(x,y)$, it gives $(y-,x)$. A swap of the coordinates is a transposition and a change of sign is a reflection. Combined, you get a rotation by 90°, that you can also recognize from the known shape of a rotation matrix.

Comment: You need to know the form of 2x2 rotation matrix, then you will always be able to see rotation when you see a matrix like this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that 
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} y \\ -x \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
You can draw a picture to see that the vector $\begin{bmatrix} y \\ -x \end{bmatrix}$ is what you get when you rotate $\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$ clockwise by 90 degrees.

You could also note that
\begin{align}
\left\langle \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} y \\ -x \end{bmatrix} \right \rangle &= xy - yx \\
&= 0
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\left\| \begin{bmatrix} y \\ -x \end{bmatrix} \right \| &= \sqrt{y^2 + x^2} \\
&= \left\|\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} \right\|.
\end{align}
This shows that $\begin{bmatrix} y \\ -x \end{bmatrix}$ is a rotation of $\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$ by 90 degrees.

Answer (score 6):

Just look how it works on the canonical base $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

The results

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} $

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $

are just one column selected from the matrix. These can be seen as a base in new vector space. Draw both bases, and you'll see how the original space was modified.

In this example: rotation by 90 degrees clockwise.

In general every *linear* operation just need to be known on base vectors. Look what it does with the canonical base, and you'll see everything there is to see.